# Difference between map(( )=> { }) and map(( )=>( )). Please look at brackets after arrow please

Tags: javascript, mapping

When using map function in js, mostly I see people using curly brackets but sometimes they use small brackets after arrow. Why is that ?When using curly brackets, I get error sometimes

Answer (score 2):

```
foo.map((x) => (x))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
foo.map(function (x) {
  return x
})
```

```
foo.map((x) => { x })
```

Is equivalent to

```
foo.map(function (x) {
  x
})
```

When wrapping in parenthesis (which are unnecessary but sometimes a useful visual aid), the right-hand side is being immediately returned. When using curly braces, you're beginning a new block which can contain any number of statements (and should also include a `return`, unless you're intentionally trying to get an array of `undefined`s).

Comment: Worth also mentioning that sometimes you need to use both in order to return an object literal: `foo.map((x) => ( { bar: x, hello: "world" } ))`